# How to show a related list custom button on Salesforce 1 mobile app

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app

I have a requirement where I have to redirect to the custom visualforce page via URL.

We have 1 `Account` record and it has `Case related list`. In the `Case related list` we have 1 `custom button` "`Ceate Priority Case`". When we will click on the button it will take us to the 1 VF page.

It is working fine on Desktop.

But when I logged in `SF1`, I went to the `Account layout`, but  I don't see any related list button on the UI.

What config or any VF code changton?es I have to make, in order to show that but

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce1 does not directly support custom buttons; I recommend exploring either a custom link or a Publisher Action instead.

Comment: Publisher actions are better than just plain buttons on a mobile interface anyways.